# Lua userdata pass by reference - local functions in different files

Tags: lua, wxlua

I have 2 Lua files, namely *mydialog.lu*a and *rangecontrol.lua*. The code in mydialog.lua is as follows:

```
local function mydialog()
    --omitted
    local wb_responses=activeobj() --wb_responses points to the current activeobj(), say Obj1
    UI.m_txt=sys.rangetextcontrol(UI.sbSizerInput:GetStaticBox() ,wb_responses) --wb_responses is passed by reference
    --Selection event happened
    --Omitted
    --If clicked on a checkbox execute the following line
    print(wb_responses) --Still prints Obj1 instead of Obj2
end
sys.tools.mydialog=mydialog
```

Code in rangecontrol.lua:

```
local function rangetextcontrol(parent, wb_txtBox) 

    local  m_txtBox=nil
    m_txtBox=wx.wxTextCtrl( parent, wx.wxID_ANY, "", wx.wxDefaultPosition, wx.wxDefaultSize, 0 )

    local function GetRange()
        wb_txtBox=activeobj()
        local ws=activeobj():cur()
        local rng=ws:selection()
        if (rng==nil)  then return end
        m_txtBox:SetValue(rng:tostring()) -- Here wb_txtBox correctly refers to Obj2
    end

    m_txtBox:Connect( wx.wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, function(event)
        wb_txtBox=activeobj() --Current activeobj() changed, say Obj2
        local ws=wb_txtBox:cur()
        ws:connect(GetRange) --There is a selection event, call GetRange

        event:Skip()
    end)
    return m_txtBox
end
sys.rangetextcontrol=rangetextcontrol
```

Briefly what happens:

1) A dialog starts and it has a textcontrol (there might be several textcontrols)

2) When user makes a selection from an object, the text box is populated.

3) My goal is to track from which object the selection is made.

*My confusion:* Although I pass `wb_responses` a userdata type, which should be passing by reference to the `rangetextcontrol` which keeps track of the selections, it seems that `wb_responses` never changes since it always prints info on Obj1. Therefore, I assume it always points to the first object that it has been initialized with in *mydialog.lua*. What could I be doing/thinking wrong?

Comment: I think you should provide the code for activeobj() to complete  your question

Comment: @Piglet: `activeobj()` function works correct since the selection shows the correct string values in `m_txtBox:Connect`. It is just when I pass `wb_responses`, its value does not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
local function mydialog()
    --omitted
    local wb_responses=activeobj() --wb_responses points to the current activeobj(), say Obj1
    UI.m_txt=sys.rangetextcontrol(UI.sbSizerInput:GetStaticBox() ,wb_responses) --wb_responses is passed by reference
    --Selection event happened
    print(wb_responses) --Still prints Obj1 instead of Obj2
end
```

You print `wbresponses` right after you initialize it. How should it change its value? There won't be any event handling between those two lines of code.

Comment: You are right, I have edited the question. `print(wb_response)` is actually inside a checkbox event. So after a selection is made, I click on the checkbox to `print(wb_responses)`